# Swift - How can I send a notification when AVPlayer gets overridden in the background mode?

Tags: ios, swift, background, notifications, avplayer

My app continues to play music even when the app is in the background and I am hoping to send the user a notification when the `AVPlayer` gets overridden (e.g. if the user uses another app that over rides it).

Currently my solution is to use a `checkInTimer` that sets up a `notification` and if the app does not checkIn after x amount of time, then the `notification` goes off, but if it does checkIn it deletes the notification and sets up another one. But this solution sucks..

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to observe [audio interruptions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/HandlingAudioInterruptions/HandlingAudioInterruptions.html):

```
import AVFoundation

func setup() {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(myInterruptionHandler), name: AVAudioSessionInterruptionNotification, object: nil)
}

func myInterruptionHandler(notification: NSNotification) {
    var info = notification.userInfo!
    var intValue: UInt = 0
    (info[AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeKey] as! NSValue).getValue(&intValue)
    if let type = AVAudioSessionInterruptionType(rawValue: intValue) {
        switch type {
        case .Began:
            // interruption began
        case .Ended:
            // interruption ended
        }
    }
}
```